# Перестал работать QWebSocket

Tags: c++, qt

Клиент на qt перестал подключаться к вебсокету, хотя сервер работает исправно. К серверу подключен cloudflare, подключение осуществляется через wss. Код : `m_webSocket.open(QUrl("wss://ayala.club:****"));`  Ошибка: QAbstractSocket::ConnectionRefusedError

Comment: *К серверу подключен cloudflare* - проблема очевидна

Comment: До сегодняшнего утра все нормально работала, и при подключение не через qt все работает